# XCode 4.3.1 download apps but does not run them

Tags: xcode

Xcode 4.3.1 has developed a strange behavior -

It will download my app to the attached device but will not run them.

I can delete the app on the device and then have XCode download the app to the device (the icon appears) but the debugger does not run it.

What gives?

Comment: What command are you running it with?

Comment: I am just running it thru the IDE by selecting the device in the scheme and then hitting run.

Comment: Does restarting the device help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the macbook fixed the problem.